# DOM XML Python, Retrieve specific data

Tags: python, xml, dom

I am currently creating a program which produces a report in python from an xml document using the dom or minidom library.

My program currently receives all the data from the xml file and prints it out. Is there a way to make it so only one 'section' of the xml document is printed?

Here is what i have so far....
Thanks in advance for any help

```js
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse('crime.xml')


no = doc.getElementsByTagName("crime")

print("Please enter a Crim Id which you would like to produce a Report for:")
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(x)# do something with x

for crime in no:
  crimeid = crime.getAttribute("id")
crimetype = crime.getAttribute("type")
victim = crime.getElementsByTagName("victim")[0]
address = crime.getElementsByTagName("address")[0]
witnesses = crime.getElementsByTagName("witnesses")[0]
suspects = crime.getElementsByTagName("suspects")[0]
description = crime.getElementsByTagName("description")[0]
charge = crime.getElementsByTagName("charge")[0]
print("id:%s, type:%s, victim:%s, address:%s, witnesses:%s, suspects:%s, description:%s, charge:%s" %(crimeid, crimetype, 
victim.firstChild.data, address.firstChild.data, witnesses.firstChild.data,
  suspects.firstChild.data, description.firstChild.data, charge.firstChild.data))
```

xml examples

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<crimes>


-<crime type="vandalism" id="1001">
<victim>victim name</victim>
<address>some address</address>
-<info type="statements">
<victimStatement> sss </victimStatement>
<witnessStatement> sss </witnessStatement>
<suspectStatement> sss </suspectStatement>
</info>
<witnesses>suspect name</witnesses>
<suspects>suspect name</suspects>
<description>house window smashed</description>
<charge>£1234</charge>
</crime>

-<crime type="robbery" id="1002">
<victim>victim name</victim>
<address>some address</address>
-<info type="evidence">
<stolenitem> money </stolenitem>
<stolenvalue> £2000 </stolenvalue>
</info>
<witnesses>suspect name</witnesses>
<suspects>suspect name</suspects>
<description>theft of money</description>
<charge>£1234</charge>
</crime>

</crimes>
```

Output example:

Reported Crime: Vandalism

Crime ID: 1001

Address: some address

(Description)House window smashing.....

Victim Name

Victims statement...

Witness Name

Witness statement...

Suspect Name

Suspect statement...

Outcome Charge: £1234

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Ideally like a report, clear headers, paragraph type text ect. However this is my next step after I am able to retrieve only one section of the xml information.

Comment: Could you post an example XML you are working with and the desired output? (edit the question and paste it there) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your pound symbol should be converted with an entity in XML to be well-formed such as the [html entity](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), `&#163;`. Otherwise minidom complains of an invalid token. And to retrieve the particular set of content under `<crime>`, simply condition your loop to the user input value:

```
for crime in no:
    if  int(crime.getAttribute("id")) == x:
        crimeid = crime.getAttribute("id")
        crimetype = crime.getAttribute("type")
        ...
```